# Confused about Silverlight Navigation

Tags: silverlight

A lot of things in Silverlight seem to be deceptively simple..and this is one of them. I have code sample of my MainPage xaml below, and Home.xaml directly after.

```
<UserControl
x:Class="RMS.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignWidth="640" d:DesignHeight="300">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootGridStyle}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="202"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Grid.RowSpan="3" Background="{StaticResource NavPageLinedBrush}" />

    <Border x:Name="BrandingBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavBrandingBorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel x:Name="BrandingStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource NavBrandingStackPanelStyle}" >
            <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource NavLogoIcon}" Content="Company  " />
            <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationNameTextBlock" Style="{StaticResource ApplicationNameStyle}" Text="Sample System" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <Border x:Name="LinksBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavLinksBorderStyle}" Grid.Row="1">
        <StackPanel x:Name="LinksStackPanel" Style="{StaticResource LinksStackPanelStyle}">
            <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="Home" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="home" />
            <HyperlinkButton Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" NavigateUri="About" TargetName="ContentFrame" Content="about" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>

    <Border x:Name="ContentBorder" Style="{StaticResource NavContentBorderStyle}" Grid.Row="2">
        <navigation:Frame x:Name="ContentFrame" Style="{StaticResource NavContentFrameStyle}" Navigated="ContentFrame_Navigated" NavigationFailed="ContentFrame_NavigationFailed" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

```
<navigation:Page x:Class="RMS.Home"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" 
xmlns:controlsToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit"
xmlns:navigation="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Navigation"
d:DesignWidth="640" mc:Ignorable="d"
Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}" Height="423" Width="768">

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Width="768">
    <Canvas Margin="0,0,8,8" Width="768">
        <TextBlock x:Name="usernameLbl" Canvas.Left="231" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Username:" Canvas.Top="185"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="passwordLbl" Canvas.Left="231" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Password:" Canvas.Top="227"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="usernameTxt" Canvas.Left="333" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="180" Width="197"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="passwordTxt" Canvas.Left="333" TextWrapping="Wrap" Canvas.Top="225" Width="197"/>
        <Image Height="53" Source="/RMS;component/gw_pro_res_CGS.jpg" Stretch="Fill" Canvas.Left="114" Canvas.Top="57"/>
        <Button Content="Login" Canvas.Left="455" Canvas.Top="275" Width="75" Click="Button_Click" />
        <controlsToolkit:BusyIndicator x:Name="Busy" Content="" Canvas.Left="318" Canvas.Top="171" Height="88" Width="228" RenderTransformOrigin="0.496,-0.184" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

After a certain method executes on in Home.xaml.cs I call this: `this.NavigationService.Navigate(new uri("/Views/About.xaml"));`

However, it errors out and says the page cannot be found. The URI looks correct. What else could be wrong?

EDIT: App.xaml

```
<Application
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
x:Class="RMS.App"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/Styles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/CoreStyles.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/SDKStyles.xaml"/>
            <!--<ResourceDictionary Source="Assets/ToolkitStyles.xaml"/>
            To extend this theme to include the toolkit controls:
            1. Install the Silverlight Toolkit for Silverlight 4
            2. Add a Toolkit control to your project from the toolbox. This will add references to toolkit assemblies.
            3. Change the "Build Action" for ToolkitStyles.xaml to "Page"
            4. Uncomment the resource dictionary include above.

            If you do not intend to use toolkit controls, delete this comment and the ToolkitStyles.xaml file.-->
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

NavContent:

```
    <!-- **STYLE UPDATES FOR NAV TEMPLATE** -->
<!-- ********************************** -->
<Style x:Key="NavContentBorderStyle" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource ContentBorderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NavContentFrameStyle" TargetType="navigation:Frame" BasedOn="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="34,0,34,34"/>
    <Setter Property="UriMapper">
        <Setter.Value>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml" Uri="" />
                <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml" Uri="/{pageName}" />
                <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml" Uri="{}{pageName}" />
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NavBrandingBorderStyle" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource BrandingBorderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,15,36,0"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5,0,0"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="NavLinksBorderStyle" TargetType="Border" BasedOn="{StaticResource LinksBorderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="33,8,33,0"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: Could you include the code for your NavContentFrameStyle style (from App.xaml or a merged ResourceDictionary)?

Comment: the NavContentFrameStyle style is located in Assets/Styles.xaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what your UriMapper looks like.

Since I don't like the slashes after the # in the address bar, mine is:

```
<Style x:Key="NavContentFrameStyle" TargetType="navigation:Frame" BasedOn="{StaticResource ContentFrameStyle}">
    <Setter Property="UriMapper">
        <Setter.Value>
            <uriMapper:UriMapper>
                <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/Home.xaml" Uri="" />
                <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/{pageName}.xaml" Uri="{}{pageName}" />
            </uriMapper:UriMapper>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

You want to navigate to one of the Uri's listed in the UriMapper.  With my code above, you'd just use

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("About", UriKind.Relative));
```

The out-of-the-box style in the VS template is `Uri="/{pageName}"`.  If you haven't altered it, you would navigate to `new Uri("/About", UriKind.Relative)`

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this out and report back!

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying UriKind.Relative.  I've found that I have to do this when working with Navigation.

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/About.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

Comment: Still no luck. Apparently the page cannot be found. I'm using the default template so I'm positive the URI string is pointing to the correct xaml.

Comment: After seeing your UriMappings, I believe foson has posted the rest of your solution :)